# SQL Select Statement on 1:M Recursive Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

| MovieID | movieName | parentMovieID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Action | NULL |
| 2 | Romace | NULL |
| 3 | Comedy | NULL |
| 4 | Movies A | 1 |
| 5 | Movie B | 1 |
| 6 | Movie C | 2 |
| 7 | Movie D | 2 |
| 8 | Movie E | 2 |
| 9 | Movie F | 3 |
| 10 | Movie G | 3 |
| 11 | Movie H | 3 |

I've been trying to output the movie name based on the ID to match the table below but I'm having trouble with the select statement.

| MovieID | movieName | parentMovieID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Action | NULL |
| 2 | Romace | NULL |
| 3 | Comedy | NULL |
| 4 | Movies A | Action |
| 5 | Movie B | Action |
| 6 | Movie C | Romace |
| 7 | Movie D | Romace |
| 8 | Movie E | Romace |
| 9 | Movie F | Comedy |
| 10 | Movie G | Comedy |
| 11 | Movie H | Comedy |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical `LEFT JOIN` will provide the info you want:

```
select a.movieID, a.movieName, b.movieName
from movie a
left join movie b on b.MovieID = a.parentMovieID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select m.*, m1.moviename genre from movies m 
left join (select m2.* from movies m2 where m2.parentmovieid is null) m1 
on m.parentmovieid = m1.movieid
```